# Webpack imports unneeded modules from nested dependencies

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, webpack, lodash

I'm creating a React application, my main dependencies are `React`, `react-dom`, `Redux`, `Immutable` and some other small libraries.
The problem is, when I build the application with `webpack`, it loads some additional modules, such as `lodash` and `jQuery`, because they are nested dependencies, which causes my build to be too big (checked with `WebpackBundleSizeAnalyzerPlugin`).
However, for instance if I only use `render` function from `react-dom`, why do I need to additionally load full lodash module? 
Is it possible to force webpack to load only necessary parts of nested dependency modules instead of full ones?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It sounds you are using webpack 1 which doesn't include the feature that you want: tree shaking.

Webpack 2 has tree shaking, which is live-code import. It means it just bundles the code and pieces of the libraries you are actually using in your application which is far better than plain dead code elimination (bundle first then remove unused code).

I run into this in the past, consider migrating to webpack 2 and you will get this awesome feature. I got my bundle to go from 30Mb to 1Mb. With minification it went down to 800k for one of those apps.

If you didn't want to use webpack 2, for whatever reason, there are other alternatives like [rollup](https://github.com/rollup/rollup). I have been successful using both. Rollup has a far easier configuration but webpack 2 is still my favorite as its incremental builds when watching assets are more efficient (faster) than rollup's watcher. Both resulting bundles had about the same size with rollup and webpack 2.

Useful links:

[Webpack 2 tree shaking](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/)

[Migrating from webpack 1 to 2](https://webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/)